# Use of rheostat in a practical potentiometer?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

In a practical potentiometer, why is a rheostat used in series to a potentiometer wire? As we move the jokey the primary circuit current will also change. So, can we cause the same amount of current flow by changing resistance?

Comment: A rheostat is simply a potentiometer where only two of the leads (the wiper and one of the ends) are used. It depends on the circuit which configuration is needed.

Answer (score 1):

The potentiometer is used to compare voltages by matching them.  At the balancing point no current flows through a galavanometer between the potentiometer circuit and the test circuit, so it does not disturb the test circuit.

The potentiometer is most sensitive when, at the balancing point, the slider or jockey is towards, but not too close to, the end of the potentiometer wire.  The rheostat allows you to adjust the voltage across the potentiometer so that the balancing point is in the most sensitive region.

Comment: You are confusing the potentiometer with the metre/Wheatstone bridge.  The potentiometer is most accurate when the balance length is a long as possible.

Comment: @ Farcher : Yes, I am assuming the potentiometer wire is being used in a metre-bridge type of measurement.  I agree the balance point needs to be close to the end of the wire (equivalent to 'Full Scale Deflection' on a dial instrument).  But in practice the balance ('null') point is identified as being in the middle of two points which are identifiably non-zero, ie +v and -v for some small value v on the galvanometer.  Both +v and -v must be located on the wire.